# How to load an external PHP file inside modal pop-up?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, modal-dialog

Scenario - I am planning to load an external PHP file which contains an Update form inside a modal pop-up on a jquery button click event.

I am able to load pop-up on button click but could not find a clear and brief solution to load an external file inside the modal pop-up. For the sake of example lets assume the edit form has just email text field.

```
NOTE- I am trying to load file locally
```

JS Fiddle - [jsfiddle.net/1aeur58f/1](http://jsfiddle.net/1aeur58f/1)

I want to display the file content inside the body of the pop-up  as shown in the JsFiddle

Comment: Are you trying to execute a file from a remote server? If you are attempting to do so, then It would not work. The file would run on the external server. Maybe you could contact the remote server administrator and get the file that you would like to execute. If you are attempting to do this on your server, just remember that PHP runs on page load. You could possibly create a class that would only be accessed when the model is open. and on page load.

Comment: I am trying to load the file from local server, could you please provide a simple example of how to achieve this ?

Comment: Of course. Just give me a minute to come up with the answer. I am in class.

Comment: So, I am unable to make up an example, but if you would post some of the model code, I will manipulate it for you to finish the example.

Comment: Sounds like you need AJAX, but the question is just way too broad.

Comment: Please refer this example, http://jsfiddle.net/1aeur58f/1/  In my case I want to display a PHP file inside the pop up.

Comment: The JS Fiddle has a 404 error, but I already posted an example.

Comment: I have updated the link, can you check now ?

Comment: If you take a look at my example. I just added `<?= 'Some kind of title' ?>` where there was an actual title. if you want to change this dynamically, then you would for sure have to use a little more javascript which I have no knowledge of. Hope my example helps you understand that you do not need to load another php file when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

So, I do not think that you have to load an external source at all. If you would like to include the content in the page, I think that you should do something like I did below.

```
<?php
$user = $client->get('account');
?>

<!-- Make the model show up --> 

<!-- Pretend this is the form -->

<button type="button" id="mymodal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><?= 'Some kind of title' ?></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```